# SPRING - My Session and Request Scoped bean behave like singleton

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web

I recently started using spring. I'm trying implement user session, but I always fail. I've spent two days to looking for the answer but I can't find it. I have used annotation and configuration xml files and nothing.
Firstly I tried writting this in applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="usuarioLogueado" class="modelos.Usuarios" scope="session">
<!-- Inyected in next bean placed in dispatcher-servlet.xml -->
<bean name="registroController" class="controladores.RegistroController">
   <property name="logueado" ref="usuarioLogueado"/>
</bean>
```

The error was: "Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread". I found the solution. I had to put the next code in web.xml file:

```
<listener>    
<listenerclass>
org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
</listener-class>
</listener>
```

After, that problem dissapeared, I became happy, but hapyness was short... Testing application in my pc and anothers in my network I checked that bean (usuarioLogueado) was still behaving like a singleton bean. I've seen in blogs the need to use scoped-proxy as follow:

```
<bean id="usuarioLogueado" class="modelos.Usuarios" scope="session">
        <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

in ApplicationContext.xml file. The namespace are:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">
```

Now, the application doesn't run. If I write any aop element, this doesn't run. I've checked with anothers namespaces, 3.1 and previous version of spring and nothing. I use netbeans ide and this ide don't give a lot of information when a application don't run. It just say "the context can't run". If I remove aop:scoped-proxy tag and use the equivalent annotation (@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)), I have the same problem. So, I thought this problem is due to context described in web.xml. I stick here this web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <!-- Por defecto en web.xml -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Lo siguiente es para que la aplicación reconozca los scope request y session -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Por defecto en web.xml -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <!-- Lo siguiente es para que el contexto de la aplicación reconozca la codificación UTF-8 -->
    <filter>  
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
        <init-param>  
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
        </init-param>  
        <init-param>  
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
            <param-value>true</param-value>  
        </init-param>  
    </filter>  
    <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
    </filter-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

I've tried with filters too. First filter I tested:

```
   <filter>
     <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
     </filter>
     <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>
```

Result, proyect doesn't run. Second filter:

```
  <filter>
        <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Result: proyect run, but scoped beans still are singleton and when I put  or equivalent annotation, proyect doesn't run.

Please help. I could not find the answer. And please, excuse me writting expression, I don't usually write in english. Thanks

Comment: which version of spring u r using? Do u have CGLIB library in classpath?

Comment: If you are using spring-mvc for all your requests, specifying `RequestContextFilter` and `RequestContextListener` is not required. [See here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other).

Comment: spring-mvc v3.1.1, cglib? sorry, I don't know what is that. I think that is the problem. I'll read spring documentation you give me here, thanks

Comment: I've downloaded cglib2.2.3 in a folder, I've made the environment variable of system classpath with the path of that folder. I've reboot my pc and nothing. A question, really is necessary <aop:scoped-proxy/> to a bean behave as a session or a request bean? can my org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener or org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter not doing its function? thanks

Comment: It work!!! and whitout <aop:scoped-proxy>. I just have to create a new simple proyect to check it